# Retrieve object by embedded identifier

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a spring boot application which has an entity, an embedded composite key, and a repository. It looks like this:

**Entity**

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEntityIdentifier id;
    private String aField, bField;
}
```

**Identifier**

```
@Embeddable
class MyEntityIdentifier implements Serializable {
    @Column
    private String idPartOne;
    @Column
    private Timestamp idPartTwo;
}
```

**Repository**

```
interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityIdentifier> {

}
```

The service is discoverable at `{[/api/{repository}],methods=[GET]` which returns a list of `MyEntity`s but the urls in the `_links` section return `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.MyApp.MyEntityIdentifier]`.

How do I create an identifier from a composite key that I can use to lookup an individual entity?

Comment: Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763250/spring-data-rest-with-composite-primary-key

Comment: thank you, I don't know how I missed that - I'll check back and write up an answer here so that in future people don't have to go clicking around to different places.